# Não está gravando informações no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Ao informar dados de cliente para ser cadastrado no banco, simplesmente não grava e não apresenta nenhum erro, eu acredito o erro esteja aqui `if($site->inserir('loja_clientes', $dados))`

Mas caso, não seja como posso resolver isso ?

**cadastre-se.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['acao']) && $_POST['acao'] == 'cadCliente'){

$nome = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome'));
$sobrenome = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'sobrenome'));
$email = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email'));
$telefone = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'telefone'));
$cpf = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cpf'));
$rua = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'rua'));
$numero = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'numero'));
$complemento = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'complemento'));
$bairro = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'bairro'));
$cidade = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cidade'));
$uf = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'uf'));
$cep = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cep'));
$emailLog = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'emailLog'));
$senhaLog = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'senhaLog'));

$val = new Validacao();
$val->set($nome, 'Nome')->obrigatorio();
$val->set($sobrenome, 'Sobrenome')->obrigatorio();
$val->set($email, 'Email')->isEmail();
$val->set($telefone, 'Telefone')->isTel();
$val->set($cpf, 'Cpf')->isCpf();
$val->set($rua, 'Rua')->obrigatorio();
$val->set($numero, 'Numero')->obrigatorio();
$val->set($complemento, 'Complemento')->obrigatorio();
$val->set($bairro, 'Bairro')->obrigatorio();
$val->set($cidade, 'Cidade')->obrigatorio();
$val->set($uf, 'UF')->obrigatorio();
$val->set($cep, 'CEP')->obrigatorio();
$val->set($emailLog, 'Email de Login')->isEmail();
$val->set($senhaLog, 'Senha de Login')->obrigatorio();

if(!$val->validar()){
    $erros = $val->getErro();
    echo '<p id="aviso">'.$erros[0].'</p>';
}else{
    $verificarUsuario = BD::conn()->prepare("SELECT id_cliente FROM `loja_clientes` WHERE email_log = ?");
    $verificarUsuario->execute(array($emailLog));

    if($verificarUsuario->rowCount() > 0){
        echo '<p id="aviso">Desculpe! Mas, já existe um usuário com este email de login, escolha outro!</p>';
    }else{
        $dados = array(
                'nome' => $nome,
                'sobrenome' => $sobrenome,
                'email' => $email,
                'telefone' => $telefone,
                'cpf' => $cpf,
                'rua' => $rua,
                'numero' => $numero,
                'complemento' => $complemento,
                'bairro' => $bairro,
                'cidade' => $cidade,
                'uf' => $uf,
                'cep' => $cep,
                'email_log' => $emailLog,
                'senha_log' => $senhaLog);

        if($site->inserir('loja_clientes', $dados)){
            if(isset($_SESSION['valor_frete'])){
                echo '<script>alert("Cadastro realizado com sucesso!");location.href="'.PATH.'/verificar"</script>';
            }else{
                header("Location: ".PATH."");   
            }
        }// se inserir

    }// else do usuário já cadastrado
}// else do getErros
```

}

Comment: Esta retornando algum erro?

Comment: Não! Não mostra nenhum erro, no banco não insere nada...
Eu acho que o erro seria a forma como está aqui: 
if($site->inserir('loja_clientes', $dados)){

Comment: Na função inserir deve estar o problema

Comment: Vou verificar novamente,..
Obrigado!